# Am I using Promises well?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, file-writing

### Probem

My problem is that I want my code to do the following:

1. Make an innitial request
2. Once I get that request's answer, I process it and make a batch of requests again
3. Once I am done with the batch, and have all its responses, I write a file
4. Once the file is done, I print a message

I got the first two steps right, but my program is not doing the last two as I expected.

### Code

This code tries to exemplify what I am trying to achieve. With only [`promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) and [`jsonfile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) it is a simple application that represents the architecture of my code in detail and it works out of the bat, provided you install both libraries.

```
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let Promise = require("promise");
let write = Promise.denodeify(jsonfile.writeFile);

let writeOutput = function(filename, content) {
    return write(filename, content, {spaces: 4});
};

//Returns a random number each time it is invoked
//after a random period of time between 1s and 6s
let requestSimulator = function() {
    return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
        let randomNum = Math.random();
        let wait = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6000) + 2000);
        setTimeout(() => fulfil(randomNum), wait, randomNum);
    });
};

//Returns an array of rounded numbers
let roundNumbers = function(someNumbers) {
    let numbersArr = [];
    let tmpNum;
    for (let number of someNumbers) {
        tmpNum = Math.floor(number);
        console.log("Rounded  " + number + " to " + tmpNum);
        numbersArr.push(tmpNum);
    }

    return numbersArr;
};

//Receives an array of rounded numbers, and for each number
//makes a new request. 
//It then sums the response with the given number.
let sumNumbersBatch = function(numbersArr) {
    let promisesArray = [];

    for (let number of numbersArr) {

        let promise = new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
            requestSimulator()
                .then(result => {
                    let newNum = number + result;
                    console.log("Summing " + number + " with " + result + "resultint in " + newNum);
                    fulfil(newNum);
                });
        });

        promisesArray.push(promise);
    }

    return new Promise.all(promisesArray);
};

//Starts the process
let getData = function() {
    return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
        requestSimulator()
            .then(number => fulfil([number, number * 2, number * 3]));
    });
};

console.log("Starting program");
getData()
    .then(roundNumbers)
    .then(sumNumbersBatch)
    .then(newNumbers => writeOutput("testFile.txt", newNumbers))
    .then(console.log("Program finished"))
    .catch(console.log);
```

After running this, you can see that the output will be something like:

```
Starting program
Program finished
Rounded  0.20890058801647582 to 0
Rounded  0.41780117603295164 to 0
Rounded  0.6267017640494275 to 0
Summing 0 with 0.05537663551196226resultint in 0.05537663551196226
Summing 0 with 0.34853429001859215resultint in 0.34853429001859215
Summing 0 with 0.988336787994851resultint in 0.988336787994851
```

Which is wrong !!!!

`Program finish` should appear last, not second!

### Questions:

So now I have doubts about my code:

1. Am I making a correct use of Promise.all ?
2. Am I promisifying the `write` function well?

Also, I am open to suggestions regarding code quality !!!!

Any help and explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `.then(['www.google.com', 'www.reddit.com'])` is going to do? Why would `makeBatchRequest` ever do anything, since it always uses an empty array of promises to pass to `Promise.all`?

Comment: In makeBatchRequest you use Promise.all with an empty array?

Comment: I'm sure OP is smarter than that and put less code in order to show his problem.

Have you tried to, instead of keep chaining on `writeOutput`, to go on this one? (I will answer, since I can't show code here)

Comment: Show us the code that is making the requests. That's the important part which you need to promisify, not the `writeFile`

Comment: @VictorIvens, then I'd somehow annotate where I have removed irrelevant && working code. And looking at the shere amount of problems in this code I'm not convinced, that the OP is experienced

Comment: @VictorIvens You are correct. The array has many promises, that I am sure of. I simply commented to make it easier to follow. I have update my comment to avoid confused readers (even though i believe it was pretty obvious ... I mean, why the hell would I pass an empty array?)

Comment: @Thomas I make no claims regarding experience, but you need to understand that this is not the full code, but an over simplified version of it in order to make it easier to understand. No code here is irrelevant. Perhaps my example could be bigger? I am usually afraid of that since many people wont bother reading it.

Comment: In my experience a question containing several questions indicates that you have not done enough work yet to isolate the problem. That said I have to immediate comments: (1) use Promise.all() not new Promise.all() and (2) if a link in a promise chain is executing before all the preceding links has finished it can only be because one or more links is not properly returning a promise for the next link to wait on.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, It was no attack to call you inexperienced. It is more about approaching one where he/she actually is *(with his experience/knowledge/understanding/thinking)*, not where we want him to be; and an answer to Victors assumption. `No code here is irrelevant` then why did you remove it from your example if it is relevant to the problem? ;) `Perhaps my example could be bigger?` yes, please. I already added an "answer" with comments on what is unclear to me/seems wrong. Maybe you can address/solve some of these points by adding the relevant parts of your code into your question.

Comment: I am working on a better sample code, which will work right out of the bat for you to test. I will post it when I have it ready.

Comment: Dear readers, I have completely remade the question. Now it has a simple example (it will run on first time!) that accurately depicts the architecture of my code, and how it fails. Please provide feedback, and upvote if you feel like it.

Comment: As a flyer, could `done()` be of any relevance here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I've rewritten the whole answer to match the modified code. My first attempt at an "answer" was no more than an extended comment of what seemed wrong with the first provided code; so nothing lost.*

Most of your code is correct, this line is actually "wrong":

```
.then(console.log("Program finished"))
```

and confuses you because it calls `console.log("Program finished")` immediately, and return `undefined`, so that the then translates to `.then(undefined)`.

it should be

```
.then(() => console.log("Program finished"))
```

And there should be **no** `new` in front of `Promise.all()`

---

Although a few things can be improved, especially your use of the Deferred antipattern. That's the manual creation of a Deferred Object when it is not necessary, when you're already dealing with promises at that place. Like this one:

```
//Starts the process
let getData = function() {
    return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
        requestSimulator()
            .then(number => fulfil([number, number * 2, number * 3]));
    });
};
```

better would be

```
//Starts the process
let getData = function() {
    return requestSimulator().then(number => [number, number * 2, number * 3]);
};
```

whereas in `requestSimulator` you need to create a `new Promise()` in order to use Promises with `setTimeout()`. There it is appropriate.

```
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let Promise = require("promise");
let write = Promise.denodeify(jsonfile.writeFile);

//OK, now this function has a purpose/additional value (formatting)
//and is not just forwarding the arguments
let writeOutput = function(filename, content) {
    return write(filename, content, {spaces: 4});
};

//fine, a mock
let requestSimulator = function() {
    return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
        let randomNum = Math.random();
        let wait = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6000) + 2000);
        //there's no need/reason to pass `randomNum` to setTimeout as a third argument
        setTimeout(() => fulfil(randomNum), wait);
    });
};

//this can be shortened to, although it doesn't log anymore
let roundNumbers = function(someNumbers) {
    return someNumbers.map(Math.floor);
};

//Receives an array of rounded numbers, and for each number
//makes a new request. 
//It then sums the response with the given number.
let sumNumbersBatch = function(numbersArr) {
    //this again can be achieved simpler by using `Array#map` instead of `for..of`
    let promisesArray = numbersArr.map(number => {
        return requestSimulator()
            .then(result => result + number);
    });

    //no `new` here! Promise.all() is just a utility-function, no constructor.
    return Promise.all(promisesArray);
};

//Starts the process
let getData = function() {
    //removed the wrapping Promise.
    return requestSimulator()
        .then(number => [ number, number * 2, number * 3 ]);
};

console.log("Starting program");
getData()
    .then(roundNumbers)
    .then(sumNumbersBatch)
    .then(newNumbers => writeOutput("testFile.txt", newNumbers))
    //this executes `console.log()` immediately and passes the result (`undefined`) to `then()`
    //.then(console.log("Program finished"))
    //but `then()` needs a function:
    .then(() => console.log("Program finished"))
    //here you pass a reference to the function `console.log`, that's fine
    .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Dear Thomas, I have completely remade the question. Now it has a simple example (it will execute also!) that accurately depicts the architecture of my code, and how it fails. Please provide feedback, and upvote if you feel like it.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, I've updated my answer to address your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Am I making a correct use of `Promise.all`?

Yes and no, the way you use `Promise.all` is weird - you always provide an empty array. `Promise.all` expects as input an array of promises, it wait for all promises in the input to be resolved OR either of them to fail.
It returns a promise that is either resolved (if all input promises are ok) or rejected (if either fails). In your original case `Promise.all` is always resolved because the input list is empty

2. Is my file really being written after ALL the requests finished, or is it being written as they finish?

The method `writeOutput` in invoked *after* the Promise returned from `makeBatchRequests` is resolved, it is invoked with two arguments - `fileName`, which is `undefined` because it was never defined in your code and the second one is `result` - which is an `Array` whose members are resolved results of `promisesArray`, which is always empty. So technically, YES, the function is invoked *after* all the requests being finished, but no data would be written to a file (oh, actually, empty string `""` which is `[].toString()` will be printed to file :] )

3. Am I promisifying the write function well?

**YES**, you're doing it right.

Other than that, try to rewrite your code, step by step, testing it when proceeding with every step and comparing the expected results with what you get.
As mentioned in the answers above, there're a lot of stuff to fix, good luck! :]

Comment: Dear agoldis, I have completely remade the question. Now it has a simple example (it will run on first time!) that accurately depicts the architecture of my code, and how it fails. Please provide feedback, and upvote if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

Well then, I think the problem might be on `writeOutput(fileName, result)`, are you sure it returns a promise?

This is more of a suggestion than an actual answer, but try doing like so:

```
scrapy.getStanceMods()
    .then(['www.google.com', 'www.reddit.com'])
    .then(makeBatchRequest)
    .then(result => {
         return writeOutput(fileName, result))
            .then(console.log("Completed."))
            .catch(error=>console.log('will catch inner errors'))
    })
    .catch(error =>console.error(error));
```

Comment: Dear Victor, I have completely remade the question. Now it has a simple example (it will run on first time!) that accurately depicts the architecture of my code, and how it fails. Please provide feedback, and upvote if you feel like it.